# String counts python with a function and input

Tags: python, string, function, variables, input

I have  this task:
Create a program that counts and displays in the terminal the number of characters of the following words. The program must contain at least one function.

This is what i created:

```
value = input("Write your word here:")
def word(value):
    word = 0
    for i in len(int(value)):
        print(value)
```

How i solve the task?

Comment: There's no question here, and don't post pictures of code

Comment: Your code doesn't bear any resemblance to the task.

Comment: btw im very begginer

Answer (score 0):

your code has to be edited. As you are beginner I added some explanation for you.
As you are beginner you can check some Python-tutorial to learn Python.

```
# write your function, which will iterate over the value
# and print each character
def word(value):
    for i in range(len(value)): # range, instead of len(value), int values are not iterable
        print(value[i])         # print the i-th value
    # you can directly iterate on value which is a string
    for c in value:
        print(c)

value = input("Write your word here:")
word(value)
```